# Como es la forma correcta de hacer una funcion iterable

Tags: python, loops, pandas, function

llevo algunos dias trabajando con una funcion que opera con datos de 2 documento `.csv`. Son muchos pasos, pero basicamente lo que hace es tomar numeros identificadores (ID) que fueron categorizados de menor a mayor deacuerdo a la caracteristica de duracion(tiempo que duro un evento) y despues aplica operaciones aritmeticas apartir de coordenadas especificas que corresponden al numero de identificacion, es decir que a cada numero de identificacion se le aplica la funcion y como resultado se obtiene un solo numero, despues pasa al siguiente y produce el resultado y asi sucesivamente.

La funcion funciona!, pero el problema es como estoy obteniendo los resultados, pues me doy cuenta que lo que hago es:

1. llamar la funcion para el primer ID
2. crear un dataframe (con un solo numero que es el resultado)
3. Guardarlo como archivo `.csv`
4. Ir por el siguiente ID
5. repito la funcion y sobreescribo el archivo usando `append` de dataframes

Creo que la forma correcta es apilar todos los resultados en una sola dataframe y al final guradarla.

Mi codigo completo luce asi:

```
#Open the file: in green put the name of the file
df1=pd.read_csv('/Users/JonathanPacheco/Desktop/Spots in tracks statistics.csv')


df2 = df1.set_index(['TRACK_ID'])

q = df1.iloc[1,3]-df1.iloc[0,3]

#selection of tracks by duration


ef = pd.read_csv('/Users/JonathanPacheco/Desktop/Sort.csv')

ef1 = ef.set_index(['TRACK_DURATION'])

sets = ef1.loc[3:, 'TRACK_ID']   # Set trajectories to analyze from time X to the end <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

M = sets.values.tolist()


for j in M:

    dfk = df2.loc[j] 
    dfT = dfk.iloc[:5] #clip trajectories at<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<



#Parameter input
    N = int(len(dfT))
    max_time = np.float(N*(q))   
    frames = np.float(max_time/N)
    t_step = frames

    data = pd.DataFrame({'N':[N],'max_time':[max_time],'frames':[frames]})

    #print(data)

    t=np.linspace(q, max_time, N) 

    #function to measure MSD (all displacement)
    def alldisplacement(dfT, t_step, coords=['POSITION_X', 'POSITION_Y']):


        tau = t.copy()
        shifts = np.divide(tau,t_step).astype(float)
        msds_sum = np.zeros(shifts.size)
        delta_inv = np.arange(N)
        delta = delta_inv[N-1::-1]




        for i, shift in enumerate(np.round(shifts,0)):
            diffs = dfT[coords] - dfT[coords].shift(-shift)
            sqdist = np.square(diffs).sum(axis=1)
            msds_sum[i] = sqdist.sum()
            msd = np.divide(msds_sum,delta)


        msds = pd.DataFrame({'msd':msd})
        return msds

    msd = alldisplacement(dfT, t_step, coords=['POSITION_X', 'POSITION_Y'])

    print(msd)    


#Saving files seccion

    b = msd.to_csv('/Users/JonathanPacheco/Desktop/MSD.csv', sep=',',mode='a')

    b = msd
    a = pd.read_csv('/Users/JonathanPacheco/Desktop/MSD.csv')
    c = pd.concat ([a,b],axis=1, ignore_index=True)
    c.to_csv('/Users/JonathanPacheco/Desktop/MSD.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

el `df1` inicial es mas o menos asi:

```
        TRACK_ID   POSITION_X  POSITION_Y    POSITION_T
0            3       1.649       0.368       0.042
1            3       1.576       0.371       0.084
2            3       1.651       0.313       0.126
3            3       1.723       0.340       0.168
4            3       1.381       0.355       0.210
5           33       1.324       0.469       0.252
6           33       1.202       0.540       0.294
7           33       1.323       0.427       0.336
8           33       1.197       0.599       0.420
9           33       1.327       0.519       0.462
10          33       1.450       0.595       0.504
11          33       1.684       0.577       0.546
12          33       1.792       0.678       0.588
13          53       1.852       0.906       0.630
14          53       1.762       0.827       0.672
15          53       1.735       0.961       0.714
16          53       1.657       1.083       0.756
17          53       1.897       1.074       0.798
18          93       1.961       1.126       0.840
19          93       2.067       1.167       0.882
20          93       2.046       1.267       0.966
21          93       1.922       1.228       1.008
22          93       1.992       1.230       1.050
23          93       1.945       1.198       1.092
24          93       2.002       1.224       1.134
25          93       1.866       1.213       1.176
26          93       1.851       1.482       1.218
```

y el archivo ef es asi:

```
Unnamed:0 TRACK_ID  TRACK_DURATION  
0             3      7652                          
1            33      6676                          
2            53      5828                          
3            93     20008
```

Se ve mucho codigo pero solo aclarar que mi problema es al tratar de llamar la funcion, lo hago con `for` `loop` y creo que no es la forma mas eficiente. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Buen día, veo que tu pregunta es un poco antigua pero con el fin de darle respuesta quise probar tu código y al copiarlo y pegarlo no funciona, ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo del resultado esperado?